# How to resize a Keynote slideshow?

Tags: resize, applescript, slideshow, keynote

I'm an absolute newbie with Applescript but I need to know, first of all, if is it possible to launch a Keynote Slideshow and then how to resize that slideshow to a particular dimension and rect on the desktop.

I know you to start a slideshow.
I Know how to resize a window with

```
set the bounds of the window 1 to {0, 0, 200, 400}
```

but don't know how to pass this command to the Keynote slideshow, if it is possible..
Any hints??

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the windows of any application by using a 'tell' statement or block. In your case, you would use:

```
tell application "Keynote" to set the bounds of window 1 to {0, 0, 200, 400}
```