# How to resize a Powerpoint slideshow with applescript?

Tags: resize, applescript, powerpoint

I tried this solution I found here:

[How to resize a Keynote slideshow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646342/how-to-resize-a-keynote-slideshow)

It works with Keynote but not with Powerpoint.

I tried to substitute "window 1" with active window but no luck.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I do to have PowerPoint so the only thing I can offer is to say that not all app windows have a `bounds` _property_, some use `position` and `size` to set its _properties_. Either look in the PowerPoint AppleScript Dictionary to see if this applies or see what _properties_ the `window` has with `tell application PowerPoint to get properties of window 1` and go from there. You might also have to use `System Events` to manipulate the windows `position` and `size`.

Comment: I can add that this:  tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint" to set the bounds of active window to {100, 100, 1200, 750}
works, but not after the slideshow is running. Now I'll try your suggestion